# Attribute Error : webDriver Object has no Attribute 'find_element_by_id' <module> driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)

Tags: python-3.x, excel, selenium-webdriver, automation, openpyxl

I am trying to use selenium 4 to interact with a dashboard.
The idea is to navigate to dashboard  URL login and navigate to username search page, and getting a username from excel file, search it on the username search page, if username is found; it will than go to edit page which opens a form where username will be replaced with a new username from excel cell and submit.

I was having error with Chrome WebDriver earlier, so I am using this in my code

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

It did solve the problem loading Chrome WebDriver but here I am kind of stuck now.
I have read online, this is due to selenium does not support `find_element_by_id` in version 4.3 and one solution I found but did not work is  `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`
but still getting this error `Attribute Error : webDriver Object has no Attribute 'find_element_by_id'`

Complete error:

```
ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(218)] [12:40:49.105] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0xF)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\username automate.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'
```

Here is the complete code.

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Set base URL and login credentials
# original values replaced
base_url = "https://dashboard-test.com"
username = "user"
password = "pass"

# selenium 4 webDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


# Navigate to base URL and log in
driver.get(base_url)
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("login-form").submit()
time.sleep(50)

# Navigate to user search page
url = base_url + "/test_users"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(50)

# Load data from Excel file
file_path = input("Enter the path of Excel file containing data: ")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb.active

# Search for and update usernames
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    username = row[0].value
    new_username = row[1].value
    
    # Search for username on user search page
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-form-query").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-form-submit").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # If username found, navigate to edit page and update username
    if "edit" in driver.current_url:
        driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys(new_username)
        driver.find_element_by_id("user-form").submit()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        row[2].value = "Username not found"
    
# Save updated data to Excel file
wb.save(file_path)

# Close webdriver
driver.quit()
```

**Update: Modified code which fixed the error but having trouble with excel: Still Working on it.**

**Here is the Updated Code:**

```
    # Navigate to base URL and log in
    driver.get(base_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_password").send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"button").submit()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Navigate to user search page
    url = base_url + "/test_users"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Load data from Excel file
    file_path = input("Enter the path of Excel file containing data: ")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = wb.active
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Search for and update usernames
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        username = row[1].value
        new_username = row[1].value
        
        # Search for username on user search page
        driver.find_element(By.ID,"username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/button").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        
        # If username found, navigate to edit page and update username
    if "edit" in driver.current_url:
        driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_username").clear()
        driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_username").send_keys(new_username)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/button").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        row[2].value = "Username not found"
    
# Save updated data to Excel file
wb.save(file_path)

# Close webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4, they've updated the remote webdriver methods and added a working code for reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
                        ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("your website url here")
driver.find_element(By.ID("id value here")) // selenium 4 update
```

Selenium 4 upgrade reference: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/

Comment: thanks @Jeeva Anand
After reviewing, I have tried the following modifications in code and its working fine now, except the excel part. 

driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_username").send_keys(username)

driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_password").send_keys(password)


driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"button").submit()